# General Purpose Interface built-in to .NET Framework

Tags: interface, appdomain

I'd am using AppDomains to manage objects in different assemblies as such:

```
object _Instance = _AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyFileNamePath, typeName);
```

I defined an interface like this

```
interface IInvokable { int Invoke(string[] args); }
```

so that I can call methods on any object that implements it

```
(_Instance as IInvokable).Invoke(new string[]{methodName,parameters});
```

I don't like this, because AFAIK any assemblies I generate will have to have a reference to the assembly where I defined IInvokable

Question: Is there any built-in interfaces that I can use instead, perhaps one specifically intended for this purpose, or intended to be for user-defined purposes. I am also open to other suggestions about how to solve the problem.

Comment: Just use reflection to get the type and the method and invoke it? So create instance and unwrap ... GetType ... GetMethod("Invoke") ... then MethodInfo.Invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is such interface, then it is a bad idea to use it. Each interface is a contract and has a meaning. Interface's definition might change with time. For example, in .NET you have different interfaces with same members, but with different names, namespaces and assemblies. And we've seen backwards-incompatible changes in .NET 4.5 when your old WPF .NET 4.0 app just won't compile when upgrading it to .NET 4.5. So personally I would suggest sticking to your current approach.

But if you still want to do it your way, then you can try ICommand and also play with Func<string[], int> ;) .

And I also wounldn't recommend doing one extra reflection operation as was suggested by ta.speot.is as reflection operations are hard for computation resources and are less type-safe (you loose some of your compile-time checks).

Also you might benefit from getting acquainted with [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx).